# set Timeout before redirrect page in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to implement timeout in this code:

```
Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('some alert');</script>"); 
Response.Redirect(Request.ApplicationPath);
```

I want to show to user message, and after redirect. But in my solution operations occurs very fast, and alert is not shown.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `Response.Redirect` and just do

```
Response.Write(@"
<script language='javascript'>
 alert('some alert');
  self.location = "/mypage.aspx";
</script>");
```

Any `response.redirect` in code will ignore any content already sent to the browser

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [META Refresh](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm) tag. This will do the redirect even if Javascript is disabled. The `10` below is the timeout in seconds before the redirect is done:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=<%=Request.ApplicationPath %>">
<script>alert('some alert');</script>
```

**Update:**

In Firefox and Chrome at least, the timeout starts from when the user clicks OK. It makes more send to put your text on the page, rather than in an alert box, e.g.:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=<%=Request.ApplicationPath %>">
<p class="alert">some alert</p>
```

Comment: What happens if the user does not click `ok` within 10 seconds?

Comment: I agree with your point however I would probably do a modal popup using jquery rather than a horrid alert!

Answer (score 0):

With Response.Redirect you send an http 302 code to the browser, "forcing" it to request another page. That's why nothing happens with your alert code.

If you want to notify the user about the transferring you can print a page with your message and a meta refresh interval. Or you can handle it by javascript:

1) Print your alert

2) Change window.location to your new path